# $_GET throws 403

Tags: php, .htaccess, lamp

I have a simple custom MVC app using $_GET to parse a url, and i've got it working on my dev server as well as a few different webhosts using php 7.1... but I'm trying to use x10hosting's free lamp hosting and the data being passed from $_GET is coming through as 403...

I've proved that it works on other servers as well as my own dev server with this

```
echo '<pre>', $route->path, $_GET['url'], '</pre>';
```

when going to the url http://app/admin... this line in my loop gives me what should be expected...

```
/admin
adminadmin
```

but on x10's server i get this

```
/403.shtml
admin403.shtml
```

I have tried encoding to base64 with urlencode($_GET) as well as disabling mod_sec in the .htaccess with

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

neither solution worked... I'm almost certain it's a server config issue but access is pretty much limited to .htaccess and php.ini .... I haven't touched php or apache in a while and am a little lost... any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: On any "free" host, access to `.htaccess` and certainly `php.ini` are also going to be very limited. My "guess" would also be a mod_security issue, perhaps based on the `url` parameter name. Try a different name. But I would imagine that you can't turn mod_security off either on your "free" host. Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper - what happens? Failing that, you need to post your front-controller, so we can rule that out.

Comment: I just found this... it appears that i need a new host... I'm working on a free budget, any suggestions for a free host that i can ftp custom php 7.1 code to and disable mod_sec? 
https://x10hosting.com/community/threads/disable-mod_security.196777/

Comment: Have you tried changing the URL parameter name? (Can you change the URL param name?) I have encountered mod_sec rules on a number of shared hosts that simply block the request based on certain parameter names used in the request. Simply changing the param name _might_ be all that's required?

Comment: OMG wow lol... that worked... thanks my friend you cured my head ache

Comment: You're welcome. I've added that as an answer, as it may help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does sound like a mod_security type issue. And, as you have found, you are [unable to disable mod_security on the free hosting platform](https://x10hosting.com/community/threads/disable-mod_security.196777/).

I have encountered mod_sec rules on a number of shared hosts that simply block the request based on certain parameter names (supposedly blocking common XSS attempts). `url` is a common one. `site` is another. Simply changing the parameter name might be all that's required.

"Free" hosting accounts are always going to have some restrictions. If this is the only thing that holds you back then you are lucky.

Comment: Actually the final thing that fixed it was to stop using $_GET['url'] for routing... instead I used $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] that fixed everything